# How to display only instock products in all of my site? Woocommerce + Wordpress

Tags: woocommerce

How to add more values to `'value'   => 'noproduzione',` ?
If i add `'value'   => array('noproduzione','10days'),` functions.php does not give me error but on frontend i receive error Warning : trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'custom_product_query_meta_query', 1000 );
function custom_product_query_meta_query( $meta_query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'     => '_stock_status',
            'value'   => 'noproduzione',
            'compare' => '!=',
        );
    }
    return $meta_query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Complex (nested, multiple relation) queries](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29642) have been supported since Wordpress 4.1.

You can then achieve a more complex query like this:

```
$meta_query[] = array(
  'relation' => 'OR',
  array(
    'key'     => '_stock_status',
    'value'   => 'noproduzione',
    'compare' => '!=',
  ),
  array(
    'key'     => '_stock_status',
    'value'   => '10days',
    'compare' => '!=',
  ),
);
```